# Change SVG fill color using MakeStyles : how to choose specific IDs in SVG file using Selectors?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, material-design, material-ui

Suppose we have the following code :

SVG File contents :

```
<g transform="translate(...)" fill="#FFFFFF" id="Circle">

       <path ........ ></path>

</g>



<g transform="translate(...)" fill="#FFFFFF" id="Circle">

        <path ........ ></path>

</g>


<g transform="translate(...)" fill="#FFFFFF" id="Circle">

       <path ........ ></path>

</g>
```

React component :

```
import {ReactSVG} from 'react-svg';
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    svg: {
        '& svg g#Circle path': {
            fill: '#fff'
        }
    }
}));

const Logo = () => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    return => {
     <ReactSVG src={SVG_URL} className={classes.svg}/>


     ...

     }
}
```

Above we have an SVG file contents and a React component that changes the fill color.

I'm successfully changing the color , but a little bit too much , since it's also changes parts in the SVG that I don't want to change.

How can we change the MakeStyles to choose only the first & second `g` tags (there are 3 , I want to change only the first `2` using Material UI MakeStyles).

Comment: Can you add a minimal codesandbox?

Comment: Are you using the same `id="Circle"` several times?

Comment: @enxaneta : Yes , I can't change them to different names , I must use only the first two `Circle` tags , and here something needs to change : `'& svg g#Circle path'`.

Comment: If you have multiple identical id values your file is invalid. Bad and unexpected things will happen. Those bad and unexpected things will likely differ from browser to browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try `:not(:last-child)` selector:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    svg: {
        '& svg g#Circle:not(:last-child) path': {
            fill: '#fff'
        }
    }
}));
```

Comment: Almost perfect thanks , but I still want to render the last child , just not fill it with white.Is it possible to render the last son without `fill`ing it ?

Comment: It shouldn't affect the last child, can't guess without an example